# A PDF to HTML converter that can handle columns, and keeps HTML trim

Tags: pdf, html, document-converter

We have magazines being produced in PDF format, two columns on a page, a mixture of text and images, but never overlapping. Is there any PDF 2 HTML software that doesn't suck?

We are looking for software that:

- Renders approximately the same layout as PDF. If it is close enough
  we will change our PDF layouts and/or write some software to massage
  the HTML in to shape.
- Does not wrap every word in a span/div. This
  tends to slow redering right down, especially on mobile devices.
- Can handle two columns of text, and not merge the two in to one long line and mix up different sentences.

It's a long shot I know. Happy to experiment with whatever software suggestions are provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I would suggest reversing/modifying your process if possible to:

1. Produce the original as one of html or rst.
2. When you are happy with it convert it to pdf, html, any other output format with something like [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).
3. You will probably find that it is a lot faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You may opt for **[PDF to HTML converter](http://www.completepdfsolutions.com/pdf-html-converter.php)**. It converts pdf to html and keep the original layout. It also offers you the preview option so you can check the file before final conversion. You can download the trial of software now to check out the features by yourself and if you are satisfied then you can go for its full version.